# Ubuntu 16 nginx fastcgi_pass php7.0-fpm.sock

Tags: nginx, php

I got a wierd head-scratching problem.

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

has

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

but the error log refers to php7.1-fpm.sock

```
2020/06/10 17:44:27 [crit] 7177#7177: *9 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1,
```

This is been a crazy day trying get nginx to use 7.0 and not 7.1 as in the error.

I have checked all config files for a 7.1 reference but cannot find one except the correct php7.0-fpm.sock reference in the sites-enabled/default file.

checked www.conf as well.

```
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

Anyone got a clue as to why nginx refers to php7.0-fpm.sock but its trying to use php7.1-fpm.sock?

I restarted nginx as well as php70-php-fpm, still not working.

Comment: Any  includes in your nginx configuration?

Comment: Error says `php7.1` and your config says `php7.0`. Have you really restarted nginx?

Comment: I lost count of how many times I restarted nginx and php-fpm. I eventually restored the server to an earlier snapshot. Thanks for the help. The real issue I was facing is posted here.   https://serverfault.com/questions/1021013/ubuntu-16-nginx-php-on-localhost

Consider this topic closed.